# Are my calculations on a matrix elements correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

The paper "Natural Language Processing with Small Feed-Forward Networks" https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.00214.pdf states:

"
For quantization, we first calculate a scale factors $i$ for each embedding vector $ei$ as

$$ s_i = \frac{1}{b-1} max_j|e_{ij}| $$

Each weight $e_{ij}$ is then quantized into an 8-bit integer as

$$ q_{ij} = [\frac{1}{2} + \frac{e_{ij}}{s_i}+b] $$
"

In order to understand quantization as described by the authors I've implemented a simple example. Are my calculations correct ?

For an embedding matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

let b = 128

1. Calculate the scaling factors:

$$s_1=\frac{1}{127}|(max(2,3,-1))|=\frac{3}{127}=.024$$
$$s_2=\frac{1}{127}|(max(-1,-1,-1))=\frac{1}{127}=.008$$

2. Quantize each weight into an 8-bit integer:

$$q_{11} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{.024} + 128$$
$$q_{12} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{.024} + 128$$
$$q_{13} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{-1}{.024} + 128$$
$$q_{21} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{-1}{.008} + 128$$
$$q_{22} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{-1}{.008} + 128$$
$$q_{23} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{-1}{.008} + 128$$

Update:

$$ q_{ij} = [\frac{1}{2} + \frac{e_{ij}}{s_i}+b] $$

should be :

$$ q_{ij} = \lfloor \frac{1}{2} + \frac{e_{ij}}{s_i}+b \rfloor $$

Which results in the following results:

$$q_{11} = \lfloor \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{.024} + 128 \rfloor = 211 $$
$$q_{12} = \lfloor \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{.024} + 128 \rfloor = 253 $$
$$q_{13} = \lfloor \frac{1}{2} + \frac{-1}{.024} + 128 \rfloor = 86 $$
$$q_{21} = \lfloor \frac{1}{2} + \frac{-1}{.008} + 128 \rfloor = 3 $$
$$q_{22} = \lfloor \frac{1}{2} + \frac{-1}{.008} + 128 \rfloor = 3 $$
$$q_{23} = \lfloor \frac{1}{2} + \frac{-1}{.008} + 128 \rfloor = 3 $$

Comment: I think you're supposed to further apply the floor function as you mentioned in the formula of $q_{ij}$ cause currently they're not integers and an 8bit integer should be an integer between 0 and 255

Comment: So in your above example $q_{11}$ turns out to be 211

Comment: @UdayKhanna thanks, yes I made the mistake of not using the floor function in my calculation. I've updated the question.